# Android Ripple effect not displaying elevation

Tags: android

My goal is to have a list item with a ripple effect on click, and an elevation. I know that in order to have elevation, currently it is required that you also have a non-transparent color for the background of the view which is making the elevation's shadow.

This is the background I'm using for my list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/ripple_color">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

            <stroke android:color="@color/border_color"
                android:width="0.25dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

As you can see I'm setting the solid value to white, and when the view is drawn it has a white background. To make sure this value was being used, I changed it to red and the view changed to a red background, so it's not like the `solid` element is being ignored.

I also made a test of switching this background out for just plain white, and that gave a correct elevation shadow, so I know the problem isn't with something else.

What do I need to add to this in order for my elevation to appear?

Comment: You are running this on lollipop?

Comment: yes it is running on lollipop on an actual device (not an emulator)

Answer (score 3):

Is your stroke-color (@color/border_color) semitransparent? I just discovered that my missing elevation-shadows came back after I changed my stroke to a color that doesn't have transparency.

Elevation won't display for shapes with transparency, and apparently , even if you solid is not semi-transparent, it won't work if your stroke is semi-transparent.

I don't know if a shape's elevation will always fail if there's any type of element with transparency in it, but it might be the case.

Comment: Nah, the border color is solid.

Answer (score -1):

If you have no problem with making `CardView` as parent viewgroup of the row of `RecyclerView`, You can use `card_view:cardElevation` attribute for the elevation.

But it requires xmlns schema :

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

you must include it in order to make use of that attribute. :)

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't actually solve the problem. The issue is that elevation is not displayed when Android thinks the background of the view in question is transparent. Since the background would be identical (just a cardview instead of a RelativeLayout) the elevation shadow still wouldn't be visible.